# add Class to element by id from within directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am adding a pagination to one of my views and I want the current page to get  bootstrap's `class="active"`. Since there is only one HTML file and the current page is passed via `$routeParams` and the number of total pages may change, I need to create the pagination with `ng-repeat` and add the active class after that. I made a directive that should do that after the correct `<li>` tag was created, but it doesn't do it. I don't know if it is still a problem with the chronological order of the expressions being resolved, or if I need to adress the DOM element differently from within an directive.

[Plunker Link here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QUQ1arUKLEOd0DzAHi8T?p=preview)

Code:

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
    <li ng-repeat="p in pages()" id="{{p}}" mark-active-page page="{{currentpage}}" repeat="{{p}}"><a href="">{{p}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Controller function and variables:

```
$scope.currentpage = 1;
$scope.pagecount = 4; //total pages

$scope.pages = function() {
    var input = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.pagecount; i++) {
        input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
};
```

Directive (might become cleaner later. atm my focus is on the jQuery):

```
app.directive('markActivePage', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            page: '@',
            repeat: '@',
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('repeat', function(r){
                attrs.$observe('page', function(p){
                    if(r==p) {
                        var id = '#' + p;
                        //I get the right id here without a problem, but the jQuery doesn't work
                        angular.element(id).addClass('active');
                    }
                });                  
            });          
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make this easier by using built in angular directives such as ng-class and ng-click. See below:

```
<li ng-click="setCurrentPage(p)" ng-class="{active: currentpage === {{p}}}" ng-repeat="p in pages()" id="{{p}}"><a href="">{{p}}</a></li>
```

You can then remove markActivePage and place  the below in your controller.

```
$scope.setCurrentPage = function(p) {
  $scope.currentpage = p;
}
```

Hope this helps